# how to get to know the details about who is currently logged in user in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp

Say i have a User whose entry is in the `Real_User` table and now as soon as the user is authenticated, how to pull the details of the user from the `Real_User` table. 
The Table is like this `Real_User ( email(PK) , firstName, lastName , password, enabled , role )`

I wish to know all the details from the above mentioned table after authentication is done so that i can prepare the views accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get the `id` from the user principal object and that `id` you can pass to your `findById(id)` method and can get the user details.

You can create a method to get Current logged in user.

```
public User getCurrentUser() {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth != null) {
        Object principal = auth.getPrincipal();
        if (principal instanceof User) {
            return ((User) principal);
        }
    }


    return null;
}
```

Comment: but i dont have any id field @Alien

Comment: based on what you are validating user for login??..userId field or something?

Comment: can you share code snippet about the principal object which extracts the email of the currently logged in user which will then find me the rest of the details @Alien

Comment: through email  , i have set username-parameter = email in my spring security file @Alien

Comment: edited the answer and also check this http://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security

Comment: Will the User possess the login details email and password ? @Alien

Comment: if your own User entity implements spring's UserDetails class then yes you will get.